# Spreading dynamic with community structure

Tags: dynamic, networkx, complex-networks

I have a data set which I hope to simulate the spreading dynamic with community structure.
The steps I follow is

1. import the data to a complex network with Networkx
2. partition the network into some modules which are known as communities
3. simulate the SIS model and draw plots with and without communities.

Something confused me between step 2 and step 3. After partitioning, I get some communities which contains nodes number. The community numbers and nodes numbers are the only input to step 3, and how I simulate SIS with and without communities?

Comment: From what I know, SIS does not use community structure. Did you find this 3-stepped method you want to apply in some article, or did you design it yourself?

Comment: Yeah, I want to do some experiments with the 3-stepped method in some article. But I do not know how to do...

Comment: Then, it would help if you could post the reference of this article, or a link.

Comment: The link of the article is [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378437111007904)

Comment: This article presents a new generative model, able to produce networks possessing a community structure. What they do is they generate different networks with or without a community structure, and study how SIS is affected by the presence/absence of such a structure. In your case, from what I understand, you want to study a real-world system, so you can't control this aspect of your network. In other words, your network may or may not have a community structure, you don't choose that. So, you can't compare how SIS behaves with out without a community structure on your specific data.

Comment: That article produce networks with and without overlapping structure, and maybe my real-world system can be studied in the same way. The community detection algorithm I have also determined. But I do not really know how to simulation the dynamic of `SIS` with `networkx` with and without overlapping strucutre.

Comment: As you say, the authors produce two types of networks, and then apply the same SIS model to both of them. But in your case, you don't control your data: you don't decide if there's a community structure or not in the network you want to study. So I don't see how you could apply the same method. It can work only on artificially generated networks.

Comment: I have thought about what you said. I think you are right and I will do experiments just to simulate the real world data with community structures. The same question however, how do I use networkx to simulate SIS model with communities?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering your last question in the comments of your original post. It corresponds to 2 different tasks: 1) artificially generating some networks (with or without a community structure) and 2) applying SIS.

In Networkx, there are many generative models, listed on [this page](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generators.html). However I can't see any model to generate community-structured networks. You could use the [C++ program by Lancichinetti](https://sites.google.com/site/andrealancichinetti), which implements a very widespread model.

Regarding the application of SIS, you could consider [Netpidemix](http://nepidemix.irmacs.sfu.ca/documentation.html), which uses Networkx for the network part of the process. Alternatively, the [igraph](http://igraph.org/redirect.html) library also contains generative models and epidemics-related models (such as [SIR](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/sir))

Comment: Sorry to reply so late. I have ever tried Nepidemix to simulate SIS model, but when I want to load my data, I failed. The tutorial does not offer instructions about how to load data from files. I have no idea about the data format to load. Have you ever use Nepidemix to load file?

Comment: I never used it, but it's explained here: http://nepidemix.irmacs.sfu.ca/documentation.html you have to use the load_network wrapper, instead of some generative function.